# Where do I place screenshots for appdata files?

Tags: github, screenshot, flatpak

I am made a program that shreds files, and as part of finishing the appdata file, I linked a image for my program to my [appdata](https://github.com/ADBeveridge/raider/blob/main/data/com.github.ADBeveridge.Raider.appdata.xml.in) file. Unfortunately the flathub bot failed with an error saying

```
• file-invalid          : <screenshot> failed to load [https://github.com/ADBeveridge/raider/blob/main/data/raider-screenshot1.png]
```

Perhaps is there an error with the location of the image?

I checked GNOME Calendar, GNOME Authenticator, which are on GitLab, not Github like mine, and they link to images within the repo. So perhaps GitLab performs some special operation that Github does not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your link is not to the image. It is to the repository location.

The actual image URL is https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ADBeveridge/raider/main/data/raider-screenshot1.png